# associate extension with app (Windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, notepad++, file-association

I want to open my ini-files automatically with Notepad++. So I right-click a .ini-file, choose "Open with..." and "choose program". Since Notepad++ is not listed I click "Browse" and select it there.
Problem: Notepad++ still doesn't show up in the list of applications, so I still can't associate it with the .ini-files. Other apps add correctly. Any ideas?
TIA
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, go to `Settings` -> `Preferences` -> Tab `File associations` -> Click `Customize` in the left column -> Type in `ini` in the text box that appears -> Click "`->`". The .ini files should now be associated with Notepad++.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks a lot. Notepad++ also shows up in the selection list, so I can now add associations the Windows way. Since I don't know what causes the problem in the first place, it might pop up again with other apps, though.

Comment: @stevenvh You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `Folder Options`, either through the Windows Explorer `Tools` menu or the Control Panel.
2. Click on the `File Types` tab, navigate to the extension you're trying to associate with a given program
3. Click on the extension, then on `Advanced`, then the `Open` Action, (or whichever action you're trying to define for Windows to execute upon double-clicking the icon for that data file)
4. Click `Edit`, then `Browse` to select the executable you wish to associate with that particular action and extension.